# Unexpected token END OF FILE at position while parsing BufferedReader to JSON Object

Tags: java, angularjs, json, servlets

I am passing an object to the Java Servlet `publishStory` using Angularjs `$http` service. And however this same servlet code has worked fine with other requests but here I am getting the following error:

[image: cmd error log]

I have researched it on the internet but could not find solution to this  particular case where I am using BufferedReader, as the same servlet works fine with other requests.

Here is my `publishStory` servlet:

```
public class publishStory extends HttpServlet{
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException{
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    Connection cn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    boolean flag = false;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    try{
        System.out.println("CALLING THE METHOD");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/storyboard","root","");

        BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject juser = null;

        juser = (JSONObject)parser.parse(reader);

        String welcomeStoryTitle = (String)juser.get("welcomeStoryTitle");
        String welcomeStoryWords = (String)juser.get("welcomeStoryWords");

        String query = "INSERT INTO stories (storytitle, storytext) VALUES (?,?)";
        pstmt = cn.prepareStatement(query);
        pstmt.setString(1, welcomeStoryTitle);
        pstmt.setString(2, welcomeStoryWords);
        int i = pstmt.executeUpdate();
        if(i>0)
            System.out.println(welcomeStoryTitle=" : "+welcomeStoryWords);
        else
            System.out.println("No data inserted");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am retrieving two request parameters `welcomeStoryTitle` and `welcomeStoryWords` in this servlet.

And below is my *angularjs controller* with a function implementing `$http` service:

```
app.controller('welcomeStoryPublishCtrl', ['$log','$http',function($log,$http){
    this.publishGroup = function(wsPublish){
        $http({
            method:'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:9090/Writer/publishStory',
            header: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
            data: wsPublish
        }).success(function(){});
    };
}]);
```

I am getting this error where I am parsing the reader object, at line:

```
juser = (JSONObject)parser.parse(reader);
```

Could this be because of the size of a String being retrieved from request?

Answer (score 0):

'At position 0' is a giveaway. You are trying to parse an empty response.

Comment: then is my `wsPublish` data is empty?